# how to call a PHP function with HTML button click?

Tags: php, html

I am a beginner with HTML and PHP and i am having problems with my code. all I need to do is to call a particular function on the button click in html. both the fuction and html are on same page. whenever i run this this doesn't generate the required output. 
I shall be very thankful for help. please help as soon as possible[myfirstpage.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0JMY.png)

Comment: onclick is for js/jquery scripts

Comment: PHP is _server side_, HTML runs on the _client side_. You cannot call PHP functions within HTML.

Comment: And add your code in the question as text

Comment: @MrDarkLynx In a way, you can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    someFunction();
  }
  function someFunction() {
    echo 'HI';
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
      <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Although quite weird, this will work, you can use `$_GET` if you want

Comment: the code works very nice. thank you.

Comment: I just need to ask one more question. the actual thing that i got to do is to make a button that on click runs a function called Upload which in turn fetches a document from user's PC and uploads on the webpage. apart from the function, what changes do you suggest should be made in  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    someFunction();
  }

Comment: @TahreemKhan Do you have the codes for fetching and uploading? Just put it in the function and it should work, well it depends on your code

Answer (score 1):

Try these code:

```js
function validateForm() {
      var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
      if (x == "") {
          alert("Name must be filled out");
          return false;
      }else{
       alert("Your name has been successfully submitted!!");
          return true;
      }
  }
```

```html
<form name="myForm" action="/action_page_post.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
  Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are communicating with two languages:

`HTML` which is `client-side` language
`PHP` which is `server-side` language

You can't run `PHP` without communicating with server.

So to achieve that you need to write `ajax` function in `javascript` to make

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "sum.php",
        data: { input: "your values here" },
        function (response) {
            alert('sum performed sucessfully');
       }
    })  
});
```

And your `sum function` in `sum.php` file

Comment: so i should place this code in html area and enclose it in <script> tag or should i put it in <?php part of code?